# Removing blank lines in the xml document

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xml-documentation

I need to read the body of msg file and convert it into xml file. I used the below code to convert msg file to xml file. 
I can able to get the xml file but problem is empty lines are displaying in the output xml file.
I used **RegEx** to remove blank lines from string. I can able to see that blank lines are deleted from the string while debugging. But after loading that string as xml file i am getting blank lines in xml file. Attached the image of sample xml file.

```
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Projects\Userdata\Source Folder\", "*.msg");
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)
        {

            string path = filePaths[i];
            string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);

            _Application outlook = new ApplicationClass();
            MailItem item = (MailItem)outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(path, Type.Missing);
            string b = item.Body;
            string formatbody = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(b, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(formatbody,LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
            var xs = doc1.Elements();
            string test = string.Empty;
            foreach (var x in xs)
            {
                test += x.ToString();
            }
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(test);
            doc.Save(@"C:\Projects\Destination Folder\" + fname + ".xml");
        }
```

**Body of .msg file looks like this**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="gateway_transaction_display.xsl"?>

 <File>

  <File_Type>AP PAYMENTS</File_Type>

   <File_Header_Record>
   <File_Format_Version>0002</File_Format_Version>
   <Creation_Module>0286-14</Creation_Module>
  </File_Header_Record>

 <Transaction>
 <Transaction_Type>FT_TRANS_IMP</Transaction_Type>
 <Transaction_Header>
   <Record_Number>1</Record_Number>
   <Urgent>Y</Urgent>
 </Transaction_Header>
 <Model_Info>
  <Model_ID><![CDATA[FF DOM INT PAY]]></Model_ID>
 </Model_Info>
 <Transfer_Info>
  <Charges>15</Charges>
 </Transfer_Info>
 <Amounts>
  <Transaction_Amount>
    <Amount>4665786.22</Amount>
    <Currency>CAD</Currency>
  </Transaction_Amount>
 </Amounts>
 <Dates>
  <Trusted_Source>Y</Trusted_Source>
  <Value_Date>2014-03-31</Value_Date>
 </Dates>
 <Bank_Account>
  <Bank_Account_Type>DR</Bank_Account_Type>
  <Bank>
    <Bank_Route_Code>
      <Code_Type>Y</Code_Type>
    </Bank_Route_Code>
  </Bank>
  <Account>
    <Account_ID>FF01</Account_ID>
  </Account>
 </Bank_Account>
 <Bank_Account>
  <Bank_Account_Type>CR</Bank_Account_Type>
  <Bank>
    <Bank_Route_Code>
      <Code_Type>Y</Code_Type>
    </Bank_Route_Code>

  </Bank>
  <Account>
    <Account_ID>D039</Account_ID>
  </Account>
 </Bank_Account>
 <Payment_Details_Or_Addenda>
  <Details_Text><![CDATA[Unapplied 
   cash &amp; intercompany settlemet]]></Details_Text>
   </Payment_Details_Or_Addenda>

  </Transaction>

 <File_Trailer_Record>
 <File_Name>AP PAYMENTS</File_Name>
 </File_Trailer_Record>

 </File>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to use Regex for removing blank spaces. Instead
 1. Trim the message content before parsing as XDocument

```
string result = item.Body.Trim()
```

2.specify loadoptions as none instead of PreserveWhitespace.

```
XDocument.Parse(result,LoadOptions.None);
```

--SJ

Comment: If i remove RegEx iam getting the error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 5, position 1".

Comment: can you show your message file? i thought it could be the problem of namespacing in root element.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="gateway_transaction_display.xsl"?>

<File>

  <File_Type>AP PAYMENTS</File_Type>

  <File_Header_Record>
    <File_Format_Version>0002</File_Format_Version>
    <Creation_Module>0286-14</Creation_Module>
  </File_Header_Record>
This is the file i tried to process. Can you tell me how to add image if you want to see the full xml file and msg file

Comment: its not possible to add file but you can copy your xml content as code in your question. if u get error message while parsing your xml document it should be the problem of invalid xml syntax.

Comment: I updated my answer and it will work as you expected

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. Same error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 5, position 1". Same content is working if i save it as .txt file but problem with .msg file.

Comment: use File.ReadAllText(path) method